# Haskell : Transform String -> [List]

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I am trying to read n on the first line then n lines of input and print the sum of the first 2 elements from each line such as :

Input:

```
2
1 2
3 4
```

Output:

```
3
7
```

so far my code looks like:

```
import Control.Monad
    
fromDigits = foldl addDigit 0
 where addDigit num d = 10*num + d

first (x:xs) =   fromDigits x 
second (x:xs) =  fromDigits xs
    
main = interact processInput
processInput input = unlines [perLine line | line <- lines input]
      
perLine line =  first line + second line
```

but I get the following error

> Couldn't match type '[Char]' with 'Char'
>
> Couldn't match type 'Char' with '[String]'

I am new to Haskell so I am unsure how to solve it.

Comment: try writing out the types, it will help in the debugging a lot!

Comment: Some hints: `type String = [Char]`. How will you read a line like `12 3` to get the answer `15`? There must be something that does something with spaces. How will you convert a character like `'7'` into a number you can add like `7`?

Comment: `interact` only deals with one line at a time, and never stops. You should read the first line, then precisely the number of lines specified by that first line - for example, with `readLn >>= flip replicateM getLine`. The type of `processInput` must be `[String] -> [String]` but `interact :: (String -> String) -> IO ()` - there are other type errors, but this is likely the source of the one you specifically mentioned.

Comment: `fromDigits x` and `fromDigits xs` one of these must be wrong. `x` is a `Char` while `xs` is a `[Char]` so the types do not match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some hints, in order:

- At some point, you need to convert your digits from `Char` to `Int` or the like.

  - Haskell won't do that for you unless you ask.  Use `ord`.
- In the `x:xs` pattern, `xs` is the rest of the list, not the next element.

  - This is likely where your `[Char]` vs. `Char` problem comes from.
- It looks like you want to treat each line as a sequence of words.

  - Try using the `words` function.
- Finally, you need to convert your numbers into printable form for output.

  - Haskell won't do that for you, either.  Use `show`.

In general, I recommend starting up `ghci` and playing with it, just to gain some basic familiarity with Haskell.  Pull up Hoogle or some other Haskell reference in another window...